# Emulator stopped responding on Macbook pro M1

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio, android-emulator, apple-m1

I started using my M1 a few months ago, at the time there was no emulator compatible with my device so I downloaded an emulator from github https://github.com/google/android-emulator-m1-preview/releases/tag/0.2 it was working perfectly fine until yesterday, but stopped responding after I changed OpenGl Es to swiftshader from settings. I tried using the arm 64 emulators but they wouldn’t work either.
I tried Android Studio Arctic Fox Canary 15, Uninstalling and reinstalling  android emulator and haxm from sdk manager, deleting android studio entirely and reinstalling it again, but nothing has helped so far.

Comment: Got the same issue. Any solutions for this? The last time I had faced this, I had to completely wipe android studio with all its' files from my Mac.